# Upgrade Ubuntu CD

Tags: upgrade, live-cd

Hello guys from Ask Ubuntu, I have a cd of Ubuntu 11.04 and I started it the Live CD, but it asks to upgrade to Ubuntu 11.10, I wonder if it will update my CD for ubuntu live CD without installing anything on my computer.

thank you

Comment: Moved comment to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The LiveCD if it is written to a CD or DVD cannot be upgraded. You can ignore any warnings if it is giving you those. You would need to create a new LiveCD if this is the case.